# Partitioning sequence with reactive extensions

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have a small question in regards to RX. I have a stream of symbols coming in from keyboard, and i need to partition them into groups. A new group should be started when a ';' symbols comes from the stream. In simpler terms, I need an operator kinda like Buffer, but that fires when a certain condition is true, rather than after some time delay or event count. Is there a way to build it with operators already present in RX, or should I enroll my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a source.

```
var source = new[] { 'a', 'b', ';', 'c', 'd', 'e', ';' }.ToObservable();
```

Here's what you're asking for:

```
var groups = source
    // Group the elements by some constant (0)
    // and end the group when we see a semicolon
    .GroupByUntil(x => 0, group => group.Where(x => x == ';'))
```

Here's a way to use it:

```
groups
    // Log that we're on the next group now.
    .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("Group: "))
    // Merge / Concat all the groups together
    // {{a..b..;}..{c..d..e..;}} => {a..b..;..c..d..e..;}
    .Merge()
    // Ignore the semicolons? This is optional, I suppose.
    .Where(x => x != ';')
    // Log the characters!
    .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("  {0}", x))
    // Make it so, Number One!
    .Subscribe();
```

Output:

```
Group:
  a
  b
Group:
  c
  d
  e
```

Comment: Wouldn't GroupByUntill create a new sequence that will be kept alive for the lifetime of the application, or am I missing something?

Comment: @L.E.O, No. GroupBy will keep references to each new GroupedObservable for the lifetime of the outer subscription. GroupByUntil will do the same thing for each, or until that GroupedObservable is terminated by the "until" selector. For this implementation, there would only ever be one GroupedObservable retained, because we're grouping by a constant.

Comment: In effect, this is accomplishing the exact same thing as Nikolai's answer, except it's only using one operator and one subscription.

Comment: That kinda makes sense, although personally, somehow I feel that Buffer operator would be a more logical operator for this.

Comment: In reality, the buffer operator should have an "until" overload that passes each buffer as a parameter. The "group by constant" logic here definitely smells, but provides the best result, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the Buffer override with boundary observable where the boundary observable is our initial stream filtered to only semicolon entries.

```
//this is our incoming stream
IObservable<char> keyboardStream;

//if the observable is cold we need to do this 
//in case of it being hot (as I would expect a keyboard stream to be) we do not need to do it
var persistedStream = keyboardStream.Publish().RefCount();

var bufferedBySemicolon = persistedStream.Buffer(persistedStream .Where(c=>c==';'));
```

Comment: this seems simple and interesting

Comment: I tend to disagree with most uses for RefCount, unless there's no synchronization required. When synchronization is involved, it's better to connect explicitly, especially when dealing with hot streams.

Comment: Specifically, the use of RefCount here is non-determinist if your `keyboardStream` is observed/produced on a different thread than which `bufferedBySemicolon` is subscribed on, and therefore presents a race condition.

Comment: Thanks @Christopher Harris for warning about the race condition issue (which I don't really get). Nevertheless, this answer is really short and simple, especially compared to the `GroupByUntil` answer which seems like using an overkill operator. If the observer is hot, and we don't `.Publish().RefCount();`, is there still a race condition, or is this answer just good ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non-RefCount version of Nikolai's answer. This provides more explicit synchronization of subscription and disposition, and should remove a race condition which occurs when your source is observed on a different thread than which your consumer is subscribed on (which is often times the case when you're dealing with UIs).

```
var groups = Observable.Create(o => {

    var publishedSource = source.Publish();

    return new CompositeDisposable(
        publishedSource.Buffer(publishedSource.Where(c => c == ';')).Subscribe(o),
        publishedSource.Connect()
        );

});
```